# How to get ScriptResource.axd? calls in HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, https

My website is HTTPS and I use a redirect module to change any requests for a HTTP page into an HTTPS page. This works nicely using this...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebPageSecurity.aspx

However, the page also gets various script resources as part of the ASP.Net AJAX and Telerik controls e.g.

```
http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/ScriptResource.axd?d=RZJPznutyCmbbBAHSbKedj3kgUyiK7uBICOoB7IdFt8MWVJ-D-TxNWt-mdkCrv5HGSAToaV2udumFlE1EKBiow2&t=7dbf7a27
```

As the majority of my site uses HTTPS and then a few GET requests to form the page use HTTP IE8 does not like this at all and prompts the user to *only* show the content received via HTTPS. If the user does this then the ASP.Net AJAX javascript files are not loaded into the browser and chaos occurs!

Is there a way I can tell ASP.Net or IIS to serve all requests via ScriptResource.axd as HTTPS? I saw on a forum someone saying they had used a handler to do this but no example code was supplied.

Would be really greatful for a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell the solution. I am also having the similar issue.